# Blur a specified class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

I am not aware if this can be accomplished, but I am looking for solution to blur one class when I click on one button. I want this, because its modal popup frame and it doesnt actually look nice over all of the text in behind.

```
<div id="contentField" class="contentField-fix">
   <h2 id="postComment">Loads of text in here</h2>
</div>
<div id="modal"></div>
```

So what I wanna do is "onClick of Proceed div" which run "modal" , to blur everything that is in class of "contentField-fix". Possible?

If not, I guess Ill need to try something else.

Comment: First correct your code please. You are not using ending tag for h2.

Comment: You do realize that by clicking on a button it would blur any currently focused element?

Comment: I think the OP wants to apply a blurring effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [BlurJS](http://blurjs.com/)

```
$('.contentField-fix').blurjs({
    source: 'body',  // Blur with the body as the background.
                     // You can specifify other elements as source.
    radius: 10, // Higher values for more blur
});
```

Comment: Allright Ill give it a try right now. Although I thought that blurJS actually blurs only background image.

Comment: Well it blurs elements with other elements. Specify other sources if you don't want to blend with the body background.